# Can we use remote config to store and load game objects in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on a casual game and as you guys know that these games have a huge amount of levels in them. So I was just wondering if we can create levels, store them on a remote config (firebase or unity) or any other cloud storage, and then load them into the game so the users don't have to update the game again when we come with new levels.

Currently, the state of the game is that we create levels and add into our levels list in level handler script which then loads the incremented level for the user.

[image]

What I found of the a unity forum is that we can store all the properties of a level inside a json file, keep that json file on the remote config and load the values (This also involves spawning the level elements and then assigning the values from the remote config.)

Is there a way which involves me to only create levels and then store those game objects on a cloud system and then fetch them. Thanks!

Comment: Can it be done? Yes. Would that be practical? Depends, but most likely no!

Answer (score 1):

I developed a similar feature a while ago using Unity's [Addressable Asset System](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@1.20/manual/index.html) (previously known as the "Asset Bundle System", which the former is built upon). I got to use it when it was still an experimental feature, but it did exactly what you're asking.

As the documentation page I linked in the answer says:

> When you make an asset "Addressable," you can use that asset's address to load it from anywhere. Whether that asset resides in the local application or on a content delivery network, the Addressable system locates and returns it.

I used it to create different versions (in different quality levels!) of the same assets that I ended up loading dynamically in the current scene.

Keep in mind that while it should've been improved since I last used it, it still had some quirks, especially with `MonoBehaviours`. It may require a bit of trial and error before you get it to work, depending on your chosen storage solution and on how you create/manage/pack your assets, not to mention it might indeed make things less "practical", but I think you should still try looking into it.

Comment: Thanks mate! Finally got some direction. Will update once I look into it. Thanks again!